# Scaling of layout depending on connected monitors in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, window-manager, windows-11

Is there a way to automatically change the Windows layout scaling to e. g. 125% when not connected to an external display but set it back to 200% automatically when an external display is attached?

---

In Windows 11 (and 10) one can scale the whole Windows "window manager" in  [several different steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6LH5.png) (note: this is different to changing the screen resolution).

Currently I've set it to 200% because I'm sitting far away from my notebook display as it is standing on my desk and another external display is connected.

200% is way to much if I'm working on the notebook not sitting on my desk.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, there is no trivial solution with onboard tools. But as I was in the same boat, here is my solution.

You need two things:

- setDpi.exe ([github:imniko/SetDPI](https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI))
- autohotkey ([autohotkey](https://ahkde.github.io/))

I wrote a script that changes on the primary display, as my interal display is only primary if it's running solo, you probably have to adjust the `display_internal` and `display_lg` variables.

Here is the script

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
; requires setDpi.exe in $PATH https://github.com/imniko/SetDPI/

OnMessage 0x007E, OnDisplayChange ; System Event: Display changes
Persistent

OnDisplayChange(wParam, lParam, *)
{
    scale_connected := 150
    scale_solo := 100
    display_lg := "\\.\DISPLAY4"
    ; display_internal := "\\.\DISPLAY1"

    ; Determine the scale based on the primary monitor
    ; TODO: find a more stable property
    new_scale := MonitorGetName() == display_lg ? scale_connected : scale_solo
    Sleep 1000 ; setDpi needs to be delayed a little bit, otherwise explorer.exe crashes
    Run("setDpi.exe " . new_scale . " 1")
}
```